# Expected value of type Entity, got "integer" instead. Type fails

Tags: php, symfony, types, entity

I am creating a form where I have a RadioButton where I select the sex of the person. But when I save the form it always complains that it is not receiving the variable of the type it owes. My question is, as I indicate to the form that RadioButton must take an instance of the entity "... \ PersonBundle \ Entity \ Sex", put 'class' => '... \ PersonBundle \ Entity \ Sex', no it works, 'class' does not recognize it as an option.

**The code:**

```
->add('id_sex', ChoiceType::class,
            array(
                'required' => false,
                'label'     => 'Sex:',
                'choices'  =>
                    array(
                        '1' => 'Man',
                        '2'  => 'Woman',
                    ),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it work and it is of the type that corresponds to it and that it is not an error. I have generated it in the following way and it works perfectly in my case.

```
->add('id_sex','entity',
                array(
                    'required'      => false,
                    'class'         => '...\PersonBundle\Entity\Sex',
                    'empty_value'   =>  null,
                    'label'         => 'Sex',
                    'property'      => 'descripcion',
                    'expanded'      =>  'expanded',
                    'attr'          =>
                        array(
                            'class' =>'radiobutton-container'
                        )
                )
            )
```